# steam opengl glx extension not supported by this display nvidia drivers

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, steam

. I got a used desktop from work and wanted to put debian on it.I did and then I wanted to install Steam.I did that. Now here is where the dumb part starts. I have had this exact model of desktop before and that one had an nvidea graphics card. I assumed that this was the same. I installed the driver and tried to boot steam. I got "opengl glx extension not supported by this display". I got suspicious and opened my desktop up. It wasn't nvidia. It was nothing. Only the integrated intel one.I tried uninstalling the nvidia one. No luck. So my question is, How do I fix this so steam will run at least until I buy a graphics card?

Here is my xorg.0.log

```
[    17.089] 
X.Org X Server 1.16.4
Release Date: 2014-12-20
[    17.089] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    17.089] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 i686 Debian
[    17.089] Current Operating System: Linux Astral 3.16.0-4-686-pae 

    #1     SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) i686
[    17.089] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-686-pae root=UUID=51d8ed27-5f54-4d84-9e51-301b32001e1d ro quiet
[    17.089] Build Date: 11 February 2015  01:14:26AM
[    17.089] xorg-server 2:1.16.4-1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
[    17.089] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[    17.089]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    17.089] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    17.090] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Aug  6 23:26:30 2015
[    17.145] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    17.169] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    17.169] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    17.169] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    17.169] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    17.188] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    17.188] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    17.188] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    17.188] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    17.238] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    17.238]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    17.263] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[    17.263] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    17.263] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    17.263] (II) Loader magic: 0xb7746700
[    17.263] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    17.263]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    17.263]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[    17.263]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[    17.263]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[    17.264] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    17.265] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:29c2:1028:0220 rev 2, Mem @ 0xdfe00000/524288, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xdff00000/1048576, I/O @ 0x0000ecd8/8
[    17.265] (--) PCI: (0:0:2:1) 8086:29c3:1028:0220 rev 2, Mem @ 0xdfe80000/524288
[    17.265] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    17.317] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[    18.444] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    18.444]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    18.444]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    18.444] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  340.65  Tue Dec  2 09:02:32 PST 2014
[    18.444] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    18.444] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[    18.444] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    18.444] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    18.444] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    18.444] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    18.444] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    18.457] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    18.508] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.508]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 2.21.15
[    18.508]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.508]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    18.508] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    18.509] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    18.519] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.519]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 0.9.0
[    18.519]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.519]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    18.519] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    18.519] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    18.520] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.520]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 0.4.4
[    18.520]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.520]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    18.520] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    18.520] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    18.526] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.526]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 2.3.3
[    18.526]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.526]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    18.526] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, HD Graphics,
    HD Graphics 2000, HD Graphics 3000, HD Graphics 2500,
    HD Graphics 4000, HD Graphics P4000, HD Graphics 4600,
    HD Graphics 5000, HD Graphics P4600/P4700, Iris(TM) Graphics 5100,
    HD Graphics 4400, HD Graphics 4200, Iris(TM) Pro Graphics 5200
[    18.535] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    18.535] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    18.535] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    18.535] (++) using VT number 7
[    18.547] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    18.547] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    18.547] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    18.547] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    18.548] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    18.555] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.555]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    18.555]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    18.555] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    18.555] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    18.555] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    18.555] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[    18.555] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    18.555] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) G33
[    18.555] (**) intel(0): Relaxed fencing enabled
[    18.555] (**) intel(0): Wait on SwapBuffers? enabled
[    18.555] (**) intel(0): Triple buffering? enabled
[    18.555] (**) intel(0): Framebuffer tiled
[    18.555] (**) intel(0): Pixmaps tiled
[    18.555] (**) intel(0): 3D buffers tiled
[    18.555] (**) intel(0): SwapBuffers wait enabled
[    18.555] (==) intel(0): video overlay key set to 0x101fe
[    18.644] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): EDID for output VGA1
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Manufacturer: DEL  Model: a028  Serial#: 809776712
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Year: 2007  Week: 50
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Analog Display Input,  Input Voltage Level: 0.700/0.700 V
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Sync:  Separate
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 38  vert.: 30
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off; RGB/Color Display
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Default color space is primary color space
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): redX: 0.640 redY: 0.340   greenX: 0.279 greenY: 0.619
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): blueX: 0.140 blueY: 0.069   whiteX: 0.310 whiteY: 0.330
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Supported established timings:
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): 720x400@70Hz
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): 640x480@60Hz
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): 640x480@75Hz
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): 800x600@60Hz
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): 800x600@75Hz
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Supported standard timings:
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): #0: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): clock: 108.0 MHz   Image Size:  380 x 305 mm
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): h_active: 1280  h_sync: 1328  h_sync_end 1440 h_blank_end 1688 h_border: 0
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): v_active: 1024  v_sync: 1025  v_sync_end 1028 v_blanking: 1066 v_border: 0
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Ranges: V min: 56 V max: 75 Hz, H min: 31 H max: 80 kHz, PixClock max 145 MHz
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Serial No: CN0787CA0D6H
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Monitor name: DELL E198FP
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): EDID (in hex):
[    18.744] (II) intel(0):     00ffffffffffff0010ac28a048364430
[    18.744] (II) intel(0):     3211010368261e78eecaf6a357479e23
[    18.744] (II) intel(0):     114f54a54b00714f8180010101010101
[    18.744] (II) intel(0):     010101010101302a009851002a403070
[    18.744] (II) intel(0):     13007c311100001e000000fd00384b1f
[    18.744] (II) intel(0):     500e000a202020202020000000ff0043
[    18.744] (II) intel(0):     4e303738374341304436480a000000fc
[    18.744] (II) intel(0):     0044454c4c204531393846500a200037
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Printing probed modes for output VGA1
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.1   78.80  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.1 kHz e)
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   25.20  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 connected
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 using initial mode 1280x1024
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[    18.744] (II) intel(0): Kernel page flipping support detected, enabling
[    18.745] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    18.745] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    18.745] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    18.745] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    18.753] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.754]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    18.754]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    18.754] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    18.754] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    18.754] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    18.754] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    18.754] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    18.754] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    18.754] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    18.754] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    18.754] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    18.754] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    18.754] (II) Unloading vesa
[    18.754] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    18.763] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    18.763] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i915
[    18.763] (II) intel(0): Allocated new frame buffer 1280x1024 stride 8192, tiled
[    18.774] (II) UXA(0): Driver registered support for the following operations:
[    18.774] (II)         solid
[    18.774] (II)         copy
[    18.774] (II)         composite (RENDER acceleration)
[    18.774] (II)         put_image
[    18.774] (II)         get_image
[    18.774] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[    18.775] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    18.775] (II) intel(0): Initializing HW Cursor
[    18.775] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    18.776] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[    18.776] (==) intel(0): Intel XvMC decoder disabled
[    18.776] (II) intel(0): Set up textured video
[    18.776] (II) intel(0): Set up overlay video
[    18.776] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 Enabled
[    18.776] (==) intel(0): hotplug detection: "enabled"
[    18.792] (--) RandR disabled
[    18.805] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    18.817] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
[    18.817] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 338 x 270
[    19.041] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[    19.041] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    19.041] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    19.041] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    19.065] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    19.065]    compiled for 1.16.0, module version = 2.9.0
[    19.065]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    19.065]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[    19.065] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    19.065] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    19.065] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    19.065] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    19.065] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    19.065] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    19.065] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input5/event3"
[    19.065] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    19.065] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    19.065] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    19.065] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    19.065] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[    19.065] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    19.065] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    19.065] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    19.065] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[    19.065] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    19.065] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    19.065] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    19.066] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input4/event2"
[    19.066] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    19.066] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    19.066] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    19.066] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    19.066] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Digital PCBeep (/dev/input/event5)
[    19.066] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    19.066] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    19.066] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line (/dev/input/event7)
[    19.066] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    19.066] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    19.067] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line Out (/dev/input/event8)
[    19.067] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    19.067] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    19.067] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Front Headphone (/dev/input/event9)
[    19.067] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    19.067] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    19.067] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Mic (/dev/input/event6)
[    19.067] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    19.067] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    19.068] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse (/dev/input/event0)
[    19.068] (**) DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    19.068] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse'
[    19.068] (**) DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: always reports core events
[    19.068] (**) evdev: DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    19.068] (--) evdev: DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc063
[    19.068] (--) evdev: DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: Found 12 mouse buttons
[    19.068] (--) evdev: DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    19.068] (--) evdev: DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: Found relative axes
[    19.068] (--) evdev: DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[    19.068] (II) evdev: DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[    19.068] (II) evdev: DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[    19.068] (**) evdev: DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    19.068] (**) evdev: DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    19.068] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:046D:C063.0001/input/input2/event0"
[    19.068] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
[    19.068] (II) evdev: DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[    19.068] (**) DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    19.068] (**) DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    19.068] (**) DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    19.068] (**) DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    19.068] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    19.068] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    19.068] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    19.069] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400 (/dev/input/event1)
[    19.069] (**) Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    19.069] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400'
[    19.069] (**) Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400: always reports core events
[    19.069] (**) evdev: Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    19.069] (--) evdev: Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400: Vendor 0x45e Product 0x752
[    19.069] (--) evdev: Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400: Found keys
[    19.069] (II) evdev: Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400: Configuring as keyboard
[    19.069] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/0003:045E:0752.0002/input/input3/event1"
[    19.069] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    19.069] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    19.069] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    19.069] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    19.069] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event4)
[    19.069] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    19.069] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "DEL", prod id 41000
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    44.456] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "DEL", prod id 41000
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    44.556] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    44.724] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "DEL", prod id 41000
[    44.724] (II) intel(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[    44.724] (II) intel(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[    44.724] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    44.724] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[    44.724] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the **libgl1-mesa-glx** package installed? Are you sure you have only an Intel graphic adapter inside your PC? If not, it could be a conflict between nouveau and nvidia proprietary driver you tried to use.

Comment: Yes, it is installed. And no, I'm not sure. How would I check?

Comment: I searched all installed packages and got this. 'xserver-xorg-video-nouveau   install
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia   install
'

Comment: To check if your VGA adapter is a NVIDIA card, use `lspci | grep -i nvidia | grep -i vga`

Comment: Would be better to only grep for VGA, to see all GPUs in the system. `lspci | grep -i vga`